# Corona storyboard new scene not working on device

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using Storyboard and have multiple scenes. I have added a new scene which works fine on the simulator but when I build an apk and install it on a device, when I try to go to that scene it does not work and the app freezes. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure if you are not missed some character when you include new scenes name, or images, because the simulator working with example: display.newimage("myimage.png") and with display.newimage("myImage.png"), but the device will not.

Comment: Thanks, I realised this over the weekend, but forgot update the question.